# trying to plot data through matplotlib, keep getting "builtins.IndexError: list index out of range."

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am pretty new to programming. My main goal is to plot csv data taken from sensors thousands of rows long. I decided to figure out how to plot simple data first. I am currently trying to use pandas and matplotlib.pyplot. On the matplotlib page, they have the direct code to graphing numerical data.

[Matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

The direct code from Pyplot on graphing data in array

[image]

I entered the code exactly as is and I get this error: "builtins.IndexError: list index out of range."

The code I entered into the Wing shell

[image]

The python shell error I received

[image]

The reference script python said was in conflict

[image]

I'm pretty lost and really don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Please include the **relevant** parts of your code, as well as the complete error traceback, as text in the question itself. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Please add code to generate the error.

Comment: Neither the error or the code picture you posted referenced any part of matplotlib. As others have said, please include your code and the full error traceback in your question, as well as the reason you think a tkinter error is a matplotlib problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Wing IDE.  In python the first element of `sys.argv` should always be the script name.  If there is no script name (e.g. you just started a python shell by typing `python.exe`) then it should be an empty string.  However, the error you are getting is stating that there is no first element of `sys.argv` at all!  This is unusual and it is causing `tkinter` (a library used by `matplotlib`) to fail because that library is assuming this element will always have some kind of value (even if it is an empty string).

I was able to get the same error by downloading and running the Wing IDE.  I am not an expert in the Wing IDE but I would report this as an error to them.  They'd have to be doing something strange to override this default behavior.

In the meantime you can workaround this issue by right clicking the file editor somewhere and selecting `properties`.  Go to the `Debug` tab and type `blah` into the `Run Arguments` window.  You will need to do this for each file you create.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Wing was recommended to me by my professor to learn python on for the summer for my internship, so I initially ran everything through Wing but transferred to Spyder because it reminded me of Matlab (the only programming language I'm familiar with unfortunately). I ran the exact same code in Spyder to make sure, and it gave the graph that I wanted without any errors, so I decided to just transfer IDEs entirely. I apologize for the formatting error in my question. Didn't know there was a specific list I had to fill out, and I'll be sure to fill it out properly next time!

Comment: @Steve Also, for exceptions and code you should put the text in itself (in a code block) and not a screenshot/image.  Only use images for pictures of a UI that is not behaving or something like that.

Comment: I've removed the following advice from this post, as it is better provided as a comment: _Also, please don't let the down votes discourage you. The SO community can be very lazy when it comes to reading posts. I believe the only valid complaint about your question is that when you have code (especially if it is just a few lines like in this case) you should put the code into the question itself rather than linking to it. It's also best to go ahead and put the whole stack trace into the question too._

Comment: (FWIW, I wonder if the advice is rather reductive anyway - the reasons why people DV are complex).